# Java 1.8 JAAS doesn't recognize the principal in my own generated keytab

Tags: java, java-8, kerberos, jaas, gssapi

Java can't find my principal name in my own keytab file?
I was expecting Java JAAS module to generate a TGT when it finds the principal in my keytab file. I also used *kinit* on the same keytab file and that does work.

Although JAAS finds the keytab as instructed through the config file, i get the next message:

```
...
Native config name: C:\Windows\krb5.ini
getRealmFromDNS: trying YEF.GSC.RD
Acquire TGT from Cache
>>>KinitOptions cache name is C:\Users\tester1\krb5cc_tester1
>> Acquire default native Credentials
Using builtin default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes
default etypes for default_tkt_enctypes: 17 16 23.
LSA: Found KrbCreds constructor
LSA: Got handle to Kerberos package
LSA: Response size is 0
LSA: Error calling function Protocol status: 1312
LSA: A specified logon session does not exist. It may already have been terminated.
>>> Found no TGT's in LSA
Principal is john@YEF.GSC.RD
null credentials from Ticket Cache
Looking for keys for: john@YEF.GSC.RD
Key for the principal john@YEF.GSC.RD not available in c:/user/tester1/keytab
```

(I used the debug flag *-Dsun.security.krb5.debug=true* to get these details, and ran it standalone instead of webstart, just to get stuff started without the webstart startup overhead)
The config file says:

```
  WEBSTART_CLIENT_CONTEXT {
       com.sun.security.auth.module.Krb5LoginModule required 
       useTicketCache=true
       doNotPrompt=false   
       principal=john
       renewTGT=true
       useKeyTab=true
       keyTab="c:/user/tester1/keytab"
       debug=true; 
    };
```

The keytab file which i generated locally on the client machine is:

```
c:\Users\tester1>klist -k -t -K -e keytab

Key tab: keytab, 6 entries found.

[1] Service principal: tester1@YEF.GSC.RD
         KVNO: 1
         Key type: 17
         Key: 0x2dccdcd29d17e2719eb5af9f1b0f7448
         Time stamp: Oct 30, 2015 15:37:02
[2] Service principal: tester1@YEF.GSC.RD
         KVNO: 1
         Key type: 16
         Key: 0xcd10890becd5fbcb526e9104765116807a5ecd38da762ab0
         Time stamp: Oct 30, 2015 15:37:02
[3] Service principal: tester1@YEF.GSC.RD
         KVNO: 1
         Key type: 23
         Key: 0xb9218bada80f02c685e1958a5042f5fc
         Time stamp: Oct 30, 2015 15:37:02
[4] Service principal: john@YEF.GSC.RD
         KVNO: 1
         Key type: 17
         Key: 0x7d4b7a98e179d7284dcd7ff3a69c890e
         Time stamp: Nov 02, 2015 13:24:37
[5] Service principal: john@YEF.GSC.RD
         KVNO: 1
         Key type: 16
         Key: 0x4ca17a0b2a58679207162cf13864c143d05e869101b5a2ef
         Time stamp: Nov 02, 2015 13:24:37
[6] Service principal: john@YEF.GSC.RD
         KVNO: 1
         Key type: 23
         Key: 0xb9218bada80f02c685e1958a5042f5fc
         Time stamp: Nov 02, 2015 13:24:37
```

But for some reason JAAS can't find john@YEF.GSC.RD , as it says:

> Key for the principal john@YEF.GSC.RD not available in c:/user/tester1/keytab

Someone on internet mentioned KVNO to be 0. So i also tested that using:

> ktab -k keytab -a john@YEF.GSC.RD -n 0

But the exact same error happened. Would like to know what java expects to find in the keytab..

Using Java 1.8.0 on Windows 7 machine

Comment: FYI there is another debug flag, in case you don't even enter the KRB libraries because of a lame config: `-Djava.security.debug=configfile,gssloginconfig,configparser,logincontext`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is most probably related to a `path` error. On your configuration you use the path `keyTab="c:/user/tester1/keytab"` and when you check it with the `klist` tool you use another path `c:\Users\tester1>`.

Your configuration should point to the right path. Giving that this isn't a Typo it should be:

```
keyTab="c:/Users/tester1/keytab"
```

Comment: Now that this works.. Is there a way for JAAS to store the generated TGT and  SessionKey in the krb5cc_tester1 cache file? I haven't found a flag for that in the Krb5LoginModule.

Comment: @Houtman unfortunately I can't help with this because I would not know if it can, sorry.

Comment: Set environment variable `KRB5CCNAME` as "FILE:<path>" to tell Kerberos libs to use a non-default cache (on Linux the default is a "FILE:" in /tmp, on Windows it is "API:" relying on Kerberos MIT process)

Comment: @Samson Thanks. I noticed that after installing the Kerberos tool for windows "kfw-4.0.1-i386.msi" things changed?! Then starting Java, I used "Sysinternals ProcessMonitor" and found that Java JAAS-LSA was accessing lsas.exe and it was able to obtain the TGT (but only for the windows-logged in user for some reason, trying another principal fails).
(i checked for the KRB5CCNAME environment variable, but was not set. I did find a registry key for the MIT tool "ccname" which value was 'API:')  Would be great if JAAS was able to access lsass.exe without having to install that tool :/

Comment: Would be great if Microsoft used GSSAPI instead of SSPI - but on Windows, alas, everything has to use SSPI because of Active Directory  -- everything except Java and, optionally, Firefox. Even cURL uses SSPI and cannot run against Hadoop GUIs.

Comment: I noticed this. wonder what the MIT tool changes.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33570059/mit-kerberos-tool-makes-jaas-able-to-access-the-windows-lsa-how-to-do-it-withou